# How to configure amazon issued free certificate to nginx.config

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

I have installed `nginx` server in `Amazon Linux 2` environment. During creation Elastic Load Balancer I created an free certificate by Amazon. Now, I want to access my server through `https` (port `443`). How can I configure this `SSL` certificate in `nginx.conf`?

SSL configuration in nginx.conf is now commented. I saw it contains two lines like:

```
 #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
 #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
```

Now, what is the location of Amazon certificate and key file location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can't do this**. ACM certificates can only be used on load balancers (LBs), CloudFront distributions and API gateway. They **can't be used** on instances.

This way you terminate your https on the LB, then from the LB there is only http connection to your instances:

```
Client ----(https)---> LB ----(http)----> Instance(s)
```

If you want to have https between LB and your instances, then you have to use self-signed certificate for that, but this is not commonly used. Usually termination of the https on the LB is sufficient.

Comment: When I access LB DNS, my laravel application's url('/') helper generates http but not https.

Comment: @Rejaul Have you setup redirection from port 80 to 443 on the LB, so that you always server https?

Comment: No but I can access to https://example.com but still laravel's url('/') giving http.

Comment: @Rejaul Probably something wrong with your LB listeners. Can you double check them if they are https?

Comment: Solved. I have configured Laravel's trusted proxies. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies